# Navigation in an iphone application

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, navigation

May be this one is easy..,
I am new to iphone development.. My question is :

I want to present a new screen after successful login, My app displays a Login screen to the user, and I have implemented the login logic in -(IBAction)login:(id)sender method when we click on the submit button.., After successful login, a new screen must be presented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using a Navigation controller you can push the new view controller onto the stack and display it through `pushViewController: animated:` method. You can also use `presentModalViewController: animated:` Or you can just add the new view as the subview of this view by `[self.view addSubview:secondView];`

you can refer

1. [Apple's UIViewController reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html). Short and sweet (relatively).
2. [View Controller Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/Introduction/Introduction.html) for iPhone OS.

**UPDATE**

Implement this in your current view controller

```
- (IBAction)buttonClicked
{
 if(validated)
 {
  // code to show goes here.
 }
}
```

Comment: I am not using a navigationView Controller.., As I think of java/c++ mindset.., the control gets transferred to the event listner i.e., -(IBAction)login:(id)sender when we press the submit button .., and I have written the logic there to check for the credentials.., Then how does the control shifts to the next view after successful login verification ?

Comment: You can use `UIViewController` method `presentModalViewController` or you can add the view as sub view.

Comment: Pls go through `UIView` and `UIViewController` reference documents. Those are clear and precise

Comment: Thanks, But I am still under state of confusion.., How does the control flow to the next view ., after clicking on submit button..

Comment: Agree that we can another UIViewController and presentModalViewController for the next screen.., I want to display those screens only after validating the credential check.

Comment: @KPK: Check the UPDATE portion in my answer

Comment: You mean., I need to implement the code for next view screen inside the "if" structure ?

Comment: yes. `validated` is a bool value that indicates the validation success

Comment: Hi..., What I followed was..., I created a root controller..and then ..., displayed a welcome screen as view1 .., when the user clicked on login button..., I implemented the logic for condition check in the AppDelegate class.., and depending on the condition validation.., i displayed view2 for successful login..i.e., [viewController.view displayView].., ... I referred : http://www.pushplay.net/2009/05/framework-for-having-multiple-views-in-an-iphone-app/  

Thanks for guiding